# Holding References to Fragments after the Parent Activity is Destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Application Flow Image (Cannot post directly - not enough reputation yet)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnlEJ.jpg]

**Introduction**

We are creating an application that manages our products. We have several types of a products (1) and each type of product has dozens of those type (2) (ex. Videos).

We have an xml files on our website that holds all the information for each product. When a user selects the type of product (1) it reaches out to our website to download the xml file which populates the product list (2). The user then selects the product from the list which then passes the information to the product single activity (3).

Oh philosophy was when creating the application to create a place where the user can download the product and materials connected to it, but have the application manage which products you have downloaded. You download everything you need so when you don't have internet connection you are still able to use the application and view the products you have downloaded.

**Problem**

Some of the products in our app are fairly large and require an extended amount of time to download. When a user is on the product single activity (3) they can download the products and when a configuration change happens we understand we need to use fragments to maintain the progress bar and text on the button.

*! The problem comes in when the user hits the back button.*

We don't want to just cancel the download for the user.

1. It takes quite a while for the download to finish
2. We want the user to have the ability to download multiple products at once.

Not canceling the ASyncTask actually lets it continue running when the user hits the back button and even allows us to send Toast messages to show that it is still running. The problem comes in when the user navigates back to the activity the UI doesn't show the file is still downloading because we lost the reference to the ASyncTask that is running.

**Solution**

We are trying to come up with a solution so that the user can back out of the product single activity (3) and come back to it later and see the status of an ASyncTask if it was started earlier. The problem is if the activity is destroyed how do we hold on to a reference to the ASyncTask or Fragment.

Comment: This question isn't very useful if you don't even let me link to an image... Please view the edit history to see the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem would be to use services. Services in Android are designed to be long running background tasks. Although you can't directly hook into the UI thread from services, you can use Handlers to post to the UI. Your service will stay around as long as they are needed (Android kills them only under low memory conditions and even then tries to stay away from the running ones).

AsyncTask is designed to be used only for short operations. It is possible to use it with some changes to run longer processes but Android prefers to not do it that way. Android specifically tries to steer you to use background threads and processes.

The problems that you are seeing are because AsyncTask (generally being defined from within the activity class) are tied to the Activity itself and maintains a reference to it. But when an activity goes to the background and has remained in the background for some time, the activity may be destroyed and GC'd at which point, the AsyncTask loses its reference to the parent. With services, it will not matter whether your activity is still available or not. You can connect to the service anytime you want and then query the service to find the status of the download.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all there are services that do background work even if your app is displayed on the screen or dead.. second of all there are threads that work and work and work.. 
thirdly there is a methon called onBind that binds an activity to a service..

your SOLUTION??

```
use threads in services and whenver your activity is called or app is opened
bind it to the service to get what you want...
```

NOTE: if your file takes some time to download, well then asynctask is not a recommended approach..that is if it takes a hell of a timee..
Hope im helpful...thnks

Comment: Thanks for the your help. It seems I need to look up services. I was told before not to use ASyncTasks and it seems very clear to me now that services are a better way to go.